# Is it possible to give windows 10 access to a sql server hosted on windows server 2016?

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2016, domain-controller, windows-10, sql-server-express

Is it possible to give windows 10 access to a SQL server hosted on windows server 2016? I have found resources for setting up a domain for my computers using a windows server.
The windows server will host an instance of SQL Server Express. I have Windows computers that will need access to the SQL server. Each Windows 10 machines will have Visual Studios and thus will need the access to the data from the SQL Servers installed on the Windows Server 2016.

Is it possible to do this without giving each user access to the domain on the Windows Server over a Network connection or do I need to give each user access to the domain and thus allowing for individual users to be given access to using the SQL Server from the domain?

I read literature on [Microsoft's Documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-windows-service-accounts-and-permissions?view=sql-server-ver15) that states nothing about Active Directory and giving access through a domain.

currently I am confused. I keep finding a lot of AZURE Active Directory articles and none for Microsoft Docs explaining Active Directory Domains for this setup I am going to setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my own problem.

1. I was able to connect to the sql server which is running on a Windows Server 2016 while having a non-domain user account access the data to visual studios on a windows 10 machine.
2. After playing around with the settings and connection of port numbers on the on premise network I found that active directory allows you to configure such settings so that you do not have to have a domain registered account user access it.
   SOLVED!

Comment: Could you provide some more information on how you solved your problem? Was there a specific problem you ran into? Was there a specific setting or port that was not properly configured?

Comment: What steps did you take to solve the problem? Can you elaborate further.